# ASP.Net Identity with episerver not working when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, episerver-8

I'm currently working on a site using EpiServer CMS 8 and replacing the login with Owin/ASP.Net Identity.

Everything is working fine on local IIS but when deploying to our test server navigating to /episerver/ doesn't redirect to the login page but directly gives a 401.2 unauthorized result.

Below is my startup class

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Website.Startup))]
namespace Website
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private const string PathRoot = "~/";
        private const string LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout";
        private const string LoginUrl = "/Account/Login";
        private const string BackendLoginUrl = "~/BackendAccount/";
        private const string BackendLogoutUrl = "~/Util/Logout.aspx";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Configuration(app);
        }
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(LoginUrl)),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                    OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect
                }
            }, PipelineStage.Authenticate);

          app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            app.Map(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(LogoutUrl), map =>
            {
                map.Run(ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Authentication.SignOut();
                    return Task.Run(() => ctx.Response.Redirect(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(PathRoot)));
                });
            });

            app.Map(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(BackendLogoutUrl), map =>
            {
                map.Run(ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Authentication.SignOut();
                    return Task.Run(() => ctx.Response.Redirect(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(PathRoot)));
                });
            });
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
        }
        private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
        {
            string backendPath = Paths.ProtectedRootPath.TrimEnd('/');

            if (context.Request.Uri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(backendPath, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && !context.Request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.RedirectUri = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(BackendLoginUrl) +
                        new QueryString(
                            context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter,
                            context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            }

            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
}
```

My web.config includes these sections

```
<authentication mode="None">
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="OwinMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="10" hashAlgorithmType="HMACSHA512">
  <providers>
    <clear /
    <add name="OwinMembershipProvider"
         type="Website.Shared.Providers.OwinMembershipProvider"
         enablePasswordRetrival="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         connectionString="TestConnection"
         />
      </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="OwinRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="OwinRoleProvider" type="Website.Shared.Providers.OwinRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I've tried to compare iis settings between the servers and I can find no difference. I really have no clue how to troubleshoot this and I've tried everything listed on the [Owin guide for startup handling](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection). The OwinMembershipProvder and OwinRoleProvider are based on the code from http://www.mogul.com/om-mogul/blogg/owin-membership-and-role-provider-for-episerver but extended and modified to fit our requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by first clearing ASP.Net temporary files and then
restarting the site with web.config set as

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Website.Startup" />
```

I had previously tested what I though was every possible combination of these two values without success.

I can't say for sure but the combination of clearing the cache and removing the assembly name from the AppStartup key may have been the solution.